# How can I define an array of custom Interface array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to define an array of products. I want to have for index 0 of that array five products, on index 1 I will have 6 products, etc. but I don't know how to declare it in typescript.

I have tried this:

```
public products: IProduct[];
public productsForRow: products[];
```

But it doesn't recognize `products[];`

My problem is that I don't know how to declare that the elements at the first dimension will be numbers, and the elements at the second dimension will be a `IProduct` array. I don't think this will work:

```
public productsForRow: IProduct[][];
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define those types outside of the class as either `type` or `interface` like this:

```
interface IProduct {
    whatever: string;
}

type products = IProduct[]; 

class YourClass {
    public productsForRow: products[];
}
```